# Cannot order array by multiple properties

Tags: javascript

I have this string `Mario:Rossi;Giuseppe:Bianchi;Roberta:Rossi;Alessia:Verdi;Federico:Bianchi;Cristina:Verdi;Andrea:Rossi`

I need to order it by last name, if is equal by first name, this is the expected output:

```
[“BIANCHI FEDERICO”, “BIANCHI GIUSEPPE”, “ROSSI ANDREA”, “ROSSI MARIO”, “ROSSI ROBERTA”, “VERDI ALESSIA”, “VERDI CRISTINA”];
```

what I did:

```
let input = "Mario:Rossi;Giuseppe:Bianchi;Roberta:Rossi;Alessia:Verdi;Federico:Bianchi;Cristina:Verdi;Andrea:Rossi";

let inputArr = input.split(';');

inputArr = inputArr.map(function(v, i, a) {
  let fullName = v.split(":");
  return {
    firstName: fullName[0],
    lastName: fullName[1]
  };
});

function orderByProp(inputArr, prop) {
  return inputArr.sort(function(a, b) {
    var nameA = a[prop].toLowerCase(),
      nameB = b[prop].toLowerCase();
    if (nameA < nameB)
      return -1;
    if (nameA > nameB)
      return 1;
    if (nameA === nameB)
      return -1
    return 0;
  });
}

let inputArrOrdered = orderByProp(inputArr, 'firstName');
inputArrOrdered = orderByProp(inputArr, 'lastName');


console.log(inputArrOrdered);
```

but the result is incorrect if the last name is equal

Comment: why do you do this? "if (nameA === nameB) return -1"
If you remove it it should work i think. If it is the same it should return 0

Comment: I would convert your string to an array of strings (last first), then use `array.sort()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sort, will sort by default in alphabetical order. So you just need a couple `split` and a sort.

```js
let input = "Mario:Rossi;Giuseppe:Bianchi;Roberta:Rossi;Alessia:Verdi;Federico:Bianchi;Cristina:Verdi;Andrea:Rossi";


const sortedCapitalized = input
  .split(';') // split the different names
  .map(name => name
    .split(':') // split the name to first/last
    .reverse() // reverse so it becomes last/first
    .join(' ') // join to create a full name string
    .toUpperCase())
  .sort();

console.log(sortedCapitalized);
```

---

Now if the issue is just with the wrong result you get, that is because you return `-1` when the values are equal. If you remove that part completely, it should work as expected.